# how do I add to the URL in an HTML submit button click?

Tags: javascript, html, post

I have a web service I'm trying to hit, URL looks like this:

```
http://servername/webapp/ws/invoices/{invoiceid}
```

I'm trying to hit the URL with GET like so:

```
<form method="GET" action="/ws/invoices">
Invoice Id: <input type="text" name="invoiceid"/> 
<br />
Action: <input type="text" name="action"/>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
</form>
```

How do I dynamically append the invoice id to the URL on button click?

Example usage: The user enters the invoice id (ex. "555") and the action text (ex. "delete"), and what I want is to hit this URL ...

```
http://servername/webapp/ws/invoices/555
```

... with a form parameter action="delete".

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks,

Rob

Comment: You can use ajax to change the form's action based on the `invoiceid` value.

Comment: Hmm ... do you mean 'ajax' or 'javascript'?  Any pointers are welcome! Thanks.

Comment: actually , Jay's solution is extacly what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write some Javascript to do this. Add an onsubmit attribute to the form tag. It's easiest if you add an id attribute to the invoice field, say id="invoiceid". Then write something like:

```
function buildUrl(form)
{ 
  var invnum=document.getElementById("invoiceid").value;
  form.action="/ws/invoice/"+invnum;
  return true;
}
```

Disclaimer: Just wrote this code off the top of my head. If it doesn't work, let me know and I'll actually test something.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I'll try that. Question: can I do: 'form.action=form.action+invnum' ?

Comment: Hmm .. tried it and it produces this: '.../ws/invoices/?workflowid=222', not what I hoped.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok -- changed it to ... 'document.form1.elements["invoiceid"].value' and it's working better, now produces: '../ws/invoices/222?workflowid=222' -- now, how do I get rid of the ?workflowid=222 part. :(

Comment: The form does a GET, so of course it adds the parameters in the query. You need to do your request entirely with AJAX.

Comment: in other words , you can : 1.Change the method to `POST` 2.use Ajax to make a request

Comment: Oh, good point about the query string. You could just take the field out of the form, make the form empty except for the submit button if you want no parameters, just URL.